# List database records by date

Tags: sql, vb.net

I need to order a table by date in a ul list.

Imagine the following table:

```
ID      Date        Name
1       02-05-2015  Example
2       02-05-2015  Example2
3       04-08-2015  Example3
```

So I want to list the sql table like this:

```
02-05-2015
Example
Example2
04-08-2015
Example3
```

How can I achieve that? It's worth mentioning that I am doing this in ASP.net (vb).

Thanks

Comment: That's a display problem, and has nothing (much) to do with the database.

Comment: Yes you are right, the help i need is more on how to organize the data that i get from let's say, a datatable for example

Comment: @MaciejLos sincerily i do not even know how to start. I can't figure how to list the dates without repeating. Should i use two cycles? One for dates and the other for the name?

Comment: @akcentx, As Marc B mentioned, it's display only issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a query that sorts by date and then use your scripting language to iterate through the results like this (I am showing in php)

```
$count = 0;
while($queryResults = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    count += 1;
    if($count == 1) {
        // IF FIRST ITERATION, ASSIGN ROW'S DATE TO $prevDate
        $prevDate = $queryResults['date'];
    } else {
        // IF NOT FIRST ITERATION, CHECK IF THIS ROW'S DATE IS EQUAL TO $prevDate
        if($queryResults['date'] == $prevDate) {
            //IF THEY MATCH, SHOW THE NAME FROM THIS ROW
            echo $queryResults['name'];
        } else {
            //IF THEY DON'T MATCH, SHOW THIS ROW'S DATE
            echo $queryResults['date'];
            //SHOW NAME FROM THIS ROW OR YOU WILL BE MISSING A LOT OF ROWS IN THE RESULTING DISPLAY
            echo $queryResults['name'];
            //NOW ASSIGN THIS ROW'S DATE TO $prevDate FOR THE NEXT DATE TEST
            $prevDate = $queryResults['date'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

execute anonymous block or create a function for this as following:

```
create table mytable (id number, date_col date, name varchar2(32));

declare
v_date date;
v_number number;
begin
  for date_rec in (select date_col from mytable group by date_col) loop
    dbms_output.put_line(date_rec.date_col);

    for rec in (select * from mytable where date_col = date_rec.date_col ) loop
        dbms_output.put_line(rec.name || ' ' || rec.name);      
    end loop; 
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order your results by the most recent DATES then all you have to do is add `order by date desc`.